# How to custom encode a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I have a custom cipher that Want to make a program in python to cipher for me. I'm not giving exact details but i'm looking to change a string into another string.

Ex:

```
"YYNNNYYN NNYNNNY YYYYNYNN YNYNNNYY"
```

would be changed to

```
"@2#6@2#1 #2@1#3@1 @4#1@1#2 @1#2@1#3@2"
```

so "Y" would be changed to @ followed by the number of consecutive "Y's" and the same "N" would be changed to # followed by the number of consecutive "N's"

Comment: So... Where is your code?  Show your attempt at solving the problem.  We don't write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to groupby consecutive and `transform` your values

Setup:

```
x = "YYNNNYYN NNYNNNY YYYYNYNN YNYNNNYY" 
df = pd.DataFrame({'chars':list(x)})
d = {"Y":"@", "N":"#"}
```

Then you can

```
g = (df['chars'] != df['chars'].shift()).cumsum()
''.join(df.groupby(g).sum().chars.transform(lambda k: d.get(k[0], k)+str(len(k)) if k.strip() else k))
```

Outputs

```
'@2#3@2#1 #2@1#3@1 @4#1@1#2 @1#1@1#3@2'
```

Answer (score 4):

I followed your description of the desired output when coming up with this `groupby` solution.  The result is a little different from your example output for your input.

```
from itertools import groupby

def convert(k, g):
    if k == " ":
        return ''.join(g)
    elif k == 'Y':
        return "@{}".format(sum(1 for _ in g))
    elif k == 'N':
        return "#{}".format(sum(1 for _ in g)) 

def cipher(s):
    return ''.join([convert(k, g) for k, g in groupby(s)])

cipher("YYNNNYYN NNYNNNY YYYYNYNN YNYNNNYY")
# '@2#3@2#1 #2@1#3@1 @4#1@1#2 @1#1@1#3@2'
```

Comment: So there'll be an `elif` for every possible character?